# Splitting a file from grep

Tags: grep

I have what seems to be a fairly simple problem but I dont know which tool I should use or how. I have a large file, a long list of programs that are archived together. I am looking for lines that start with a capital O followed by 4-6 numbers as the beginning of a program. I would like to split the file here and rename the new file the matched expression line. The following would be typical of what grep shows me

```
grep -E '[O]+([0-9]+[0-9]+)' mybigfile.nc

O7749
O11000
O39441
O1992
```

What is the best tool to send to from grep to split this up?

Thank you!

Comment: I think grep is not the command you need. Try with sed. You can print lines before matching string and print lines after matching string with sed

Comment: ... or something like `awk '/^O[0-9]{4,6}/{close(f); f = $0} {print > f}' mybigfile.nc`

Comment: @steeldriver I had to add quotes to {print > "f"} to get it to run but it still isnt separating my file. It just makes a copy of the file called f. I want to take everything from the Oxxxx line to the next Oxxxx line and make it a separate file. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You could try getting line number where pattern matches using grep command (grep -c, grep -n), than you can use sed command to grab content between two line numbers(sed -n <line-no1>,<line-no2>p file). You can iterate this process in shell script with keeping track of line numbers.

Comment: @reToddFerreal my suggestion may have failed because `f` is initially empty - if your file doesn't *start* with a `Oxxxx` line. Try `awk '/^O[0-9]{4,6}/{close(f); f = $0} f{print > f}' mybigfile.nc`

Comment: @steeldriver Im getting a different error now but one I can work with I think. I like figuring it out if I have something that kinda works lol. But, HOLY SHIT! This is great, thank you!

Comment: @steeldriver Just to show you what I get with your line. ```awk '/^O[0-9]{4,6}/{close(f); f = $0} f{print > f}' VF3-40TAPER.ALL.NC
' (No such file or directory)F3-40TAPER.ALL.NC FNR=2877) fatal: can't redirect to `O00005 (DANCER/BRAKE MOUNTING BLOCK OP1)```   But this is trying to be perfect lmao. Thanks again

Comment: @reToddFerreal it's hard to comment without a representative sample of your `mybigfile.nc`, however likely the issue is that `/` is not a legal character in filenames

Comment: @steeldriver https://pastebin.com/14rjiQpd